# How to suppress spaces around template variables

Tags: django-templates

first timer here, so please be gentle.

I am trying to output a list of Authors, separated by commas, using Django. This is what I want to achieve:

> Jon Doe, Alan Smith, Paul K Keating

Sounds simple enough, but if I use this code in my template, extra spaces are inserted around the comma separators:

```
{% for author in authors %}
    {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}
    {% if not forloop.last %}
        ,
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The output is:

> Jon Doe , Alan Smith , Paul K Keating

Note the extra whitespace before the comma separators. The only way I have found so far to avoid this is:

```
{% for author in authors %}
    {% if not forloop.last %}
        {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }},
    {% else %}
        {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This produces the correct output, but it seems to go against DRY. Is there a better / more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: Have you tried {{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}? I mean, without indentation?

Comment: Thanks, that works! But I don't understand why, to be honest. Does django add whitespace when it encounters a new line?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think is problem of html.